# Webpack dev server proxy router option doesn't work

Tags: webpack-dev-server, vue-cli, http-proxy-middleware

I'm setting up an application using the Vue CLI. I've come to configuring the proxy of the `webpack-dev-server` to proxy requests to a certain endpoint. Which endpoint to proxy to differs based on certain request parameters.

According to the `http-proxy` documentation, I should be able to do this using the `router` option (instead of the `target` property, but the `target` property is required by `webpack-dev-server`). Here's a minimal version of my proxy configuration:

```js
{
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    host: 'localhost',
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000',
        router: function (req) {
          console.log('Proxy router', req.hostname);
          return 'http://localhost:7000';
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
```

What I'd expect to happen here is that any requests made to `http://localhost:8080/api` would be proxied to `http://localhost:7000`. What actually happens is that it tries to proxy the requests to the endpoint configured in the `target` option.

To illustrate this, this is the console output:

> Proxy router localhost
>
> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/test from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8000/.
>
> See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

It executes the router function (as seen by the console log output above), but it seems to just ignore the result and proxy to the target endpoint anyway. According to the `http-proxy` docs, the `target` option isn't required when using the `router` option, so I would have removed it if I could, but `webpack-dev-server` itself requires the `target` option to be set and be a valid URI.

How can I get the proxy to use the router function in `webpack-dev-server`?

Comment: I suspect it *is* working, but the feedback is incorrect if the request fails (or it falls back to the original `target`, not sure). If I use a basic `"/api": { "target": "http://localhost:4321", "router": () => "http://localhost:3100" }` in https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/master/client/webpack/dev.config.js, for example, when the backend is up on 3100 it works fine, but when the backend is *down* it reports failure to proxy *to 4321*.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the case. You're welcome to post it as the answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the underlying `http-proxy-middleware`. Although that configuration *does* successfully proxy the request to `/api` to `http://localhost:7000`, if the proxied request *fails* the original `target` is logged:

```js
const target = (this.proxyOptions.target as any).host || this.proxyOptions.target;
const errorMessage =
  '[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request %s from %s to %s (%s) (%s)';
```

[Source](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/5e79b93f6bcb8c05bd4bbbb060542d4d07db7e2e/src/http-proxy-middleware.ts#L171-L172)

If you turn up the log level, you can see that it is using the desired target:

```js
'/api': {
  target: 'http://localhost:8000',
  router: function () {
    return 'http://localhost:7000';
  },
  logLevel: 'debug',
},
```

```
[HPM] Router new target: http://localhost:8000 -> "http://localhost:7000"
[HPM] GET /api => http://localhost:7000
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

It looks like this was [fixed in v1.1.2](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/releases/tag/v1.1.2).